# Laravel and Mailgun: Incoming Email Subject

Tags: php, laravel, email, mailgun, subject

I'm currently using Mailgun to check received emails in my application. So far I can get the recipient, the sender, and the body of the email; but not the subject.

```
$recipient = $request->input('recipient'); <-- Working
$sender = $request->input('sender'); <-- Working
$body = $request->input('body-html'); <-- Working
$subject = $request->input('subject'); <-- Not Working
```

I can see the subject in the message header:

```
$headers = $request->input('message-headers');
```

Which returns the **following:**

```
[["Received", "by luna.mailgun.net with SMTP mgrt 8734663311733; Fri, 03 May 2013 18:26:27 +0000"], ["Content-Type", ["multipart/alternative", {"boundary": "eb663d73ae0a4d6c9153cc0aec8b7520"}]], ["Mime-Version", "1.0"], ["Subject", "Test deliver webhook"], ["From", "Bob <bob@thewardensaga.com>"], ["To", "Alice <alice@example.com>"], ["Message-Id", "<20130503182626.18666.16540@thewardensaga.com>"], ["X-Mailgun-Variables", "{\"my_var_1\": \"Mailgun Variable #1\", \"my-var-2\": \"awesome\"}"], ["Date", "Fri, 03 May 2013 18:26:27 +0000"], ["Sender", "bob@thewardensaga.com"]]
```

This looks to be an array but running it through is_array, returns false.

Code that I have tried:

```
foreach($headers as $header) {
    if($header[0] == 'Subject') {
        $subject = $header[1];
    }
}
return $subject;
```

> RETURNS: ErrorException Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: Maybe `message-headers` is a json string. Try using `json_decode` on it before using in the foreach.

Answer (score 0):

```
$subject = null;
foreach ($data as $header) {
    if ($header[0] == 'Subject') {
        $subject = $header[1];
        break;
    }
}
```